# Examples for infinite Hamiltonian group having a infinite order 2-group as a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

During teaching some basic concepts about a Hamiltonian group, I was asked about an infinite sample. According to what `D.J. Robinson` cited, we have a very good frame for this kind of interesting group:

> (Dedekind-Baer): A Hamiltonian group $G$ can be written as
>                   $${G={Q}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}^{k}\times H.}$$ wherein $H$ is an abelian group with all its elements of odd order.

Obviously, while $G$ is finite then $|G|=2^{3+k}|H|$ and so $Q_8$ is the smallest one in this class of groups. In that time, we thought of an example of infinite one and then concluded that we could take $H=\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ where $p$ is **odd** prime. Do you know any other infinite $H$ satisfying the above definition? Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a direct sum of infinitely many finite abelian groups of order $3$.

Comment: Hamiltonian groups are supposed to be nonabelian, so perhaps you should take a direct product with $Q_8$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes! indeed we can take `Q_8 x (Z_3 x...x Z_3...)` for example.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sure, of course.  I thought that the OP just wanted the $H$ part.

Comment: @James You are absolutely right - I misread the question!

Comment: @James: Dear friend, may I ask your point of views about one of my question? May I? Thanks

Comment: @BabakS. If you post a link to the question I will look at it.  But bear in mind that I cannot promise that I'll have anything useful to contribute!

Answer (score 1):

In general a Hamiltonian group is a direct product of $Q_8$, a group of exponent $2$, and an abelian periodic group in which all elements have odd order. This is proved in Marshall Hall's book on group Theory, for example.