# Can you give me an infinite non abelian group in which every subgroup is normal?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

I know that every subgroup of an abelian group is normal and the converse is not true . For an example $Q_8=\{\pm 1 ,\pm i, \pm j, \pm k \}$.

My question : Can you give me an infinite non abelian group in which every subgroup is normal?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/909502)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a Hamilton group. The infinite Hamilton groups were classified by Baer. One example is $Q_8\times \prod_{n=1}^\infty C_3$. See the Wikipedia article.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/909514)